# Displaying snackbar at the top/bottom of desired component in react-native

Tags: react-native

It would be nice to have the snack bar displayed at the top/bottom of required components instead of displaying at the very bottom of the whole app. This is especially useful if the app has tabBar at the bottom or when the snack bar has to show on top (again not at the very top but at the top of the desired component)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ramesh you can use this module for displaying snackbar from top/botom.

[react-native-snackbar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@prince8verma/react-native-snackbar)

Comment: Instead of recommending any other package, You could share the styling code with him.

Answer (score 2):

SnackBar is just a regular view with some functionality (like swipe to dismiss, auto dismiss after sometime). You can display it anywhere you wish. In your case you can use a absolute view with bottom equal to the height of the tab bar.

You can refer https://github.com/chethann/react-native-snackbar to get some idea.